# Wordpress is_user_logged_in fails with space in username

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

In our latest wordpress site, username a-bcomm logged in, seeing dashbaord and usermeta, is_user_logged_in() returns true.

Change the username in sql to a bcomm and in exactly the same circumstances is_user_logged_in() returns false.

Change it back in sql to a-bcomm and again is_user_logged_in() is true.

Any thoughts?

thanks

(Edited to add sql and code)

The sql to change the username internally is...

```
update wp_users set user_login= 'a bcomm' where id=XX;
```

wordpress works fine if this change is made (AFAIK - we've had to do this multiple times for users in the past). NOTE This happens with a new user too, this is not a "can't change WP usernames" issue.

The code that works when username is a-bcomm but not a bcomm is

```
        if(is_user_logged_in())  
    {
        $user_name = $current_user -> user_login;
        $user_id = $current_user -> ID;
        error_log("USer logged in $user_name");
    } else {
        if ($user) {
            $user_id = $user->ID;
            $user_name = $user->user_login;
            error_log("User NOT logged in $user_name");
        }
        error_log("User not logged in no user ".print_r($current_user,true));
    }
```

with a bcomm the final error_log entry prints, with a-bcomm the first one prints

THX

Comment: Just a guess. Usernames cannot be changed in WP?

Comment: what is the exact field do you change?